# MySQL Communications link failure due to underlying exception

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc, eofexception

I am facing such annoying problem,
running on Tomcat 6 and MySQL using TomcatJDBC Lib.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException:
```

Communications link failure due to underlying exception:

```
** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.io.EOFException

STACKTRACE:

java.io.EOFException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:1934)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2380)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2909)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1600)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1695)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3026)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1137)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1231)
```

After some time (20sh mins) this occurs, all connections to db seems to expire.

```
autoReconnect=true" 
validationQuery="Select 1"
```

Everything is set.
I do handle reconnect to database, and it works fine, but huge log files are bad, i cant either handle this exception to make it silent. Also this type of "fixing" isn't right solution. Is there any way to:
a) Handle this exception silently
b) Fix this issue (i do not have any firewall that i know of) (dont have access to my.cnf for mysql configuration)

Also having this problem on Tomcat 5 with Apache jConnector on totaly different application, without any firewalls that could drop a connection.
*(Catching EOFException or CommunicationsException on method that does invoke connection doesn't help of course.)*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your JDBC URL?  I assume `autoReconnect=true` is part of the URL?  Where are you defining the `validationQuery`?

Comment: url="jdbc:mysql://adress/dbName?autoReconnect=true" validationQuery="Select 1"

Comment: Where is the `validationQuery` defined @BShip?

Comment: in context.xml the same line wheres url<Resource name="jdbc/mydb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" maxActive="30" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1"
               username="xxx" password="xxx" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://server/mydb?autoReconnect=true" validationQuery="Select 1"/>

Comment: Sorry, I'm ignorant of Tomcat's configs.  I don't see a problem with this. Looks to me that you are doing the right thing.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

a) Stop MySQL db server and application server (Tomcat or else).

b) Mysql settings: This should be done in "my.ini" file under mysql folder.

wait_timeout =1200 (i.e 20 min – Keep same time of your firewall OR any other third party software)

You can set it DB level by above query. set  wait_timeout =1200;

View settings by above query Show variables like 'wait_timeout'  ;

c)  Add two properties in “Torque.properties” file.

## minEvictableIdleTimeMillis  A the time in millisecond a connection can stay idle in the pool

```
    torque.dsfactory.csa.pool.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 1100000
```

#timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis A the time in millisecond between the run of the  eviction thread; must be greater than 0; default to -1

```
  torque.dsfactory.csa.pool.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 2000


    d) Start application and db server
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the status of MYSQL by using command /s 
now check the port number that you have mentioned in the code and that should match with  MYSQL  port 
if port numbers are different change it

(jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mrt) 
in this example my port number is 3306

Answer (score 1):

you need to set MaxIdle and Timeout property in server.xml file in resource.